# php - Class not found (composer.json)

Tags: php, json, content-management-system, composer-php

I'm trying to implement [a PHP Library for detecting CMS](https://github.com/Krisseck/Detect-CMS) I found on github, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I am new to php and composer, but I installed composer in my directory, then updated the json as instructed, but it cannot find the classes, despite them all being in the directory.

running this code

```
include(__DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php");
$domain = "http://google.com";
$cms = new DetectCMS($domain);
if($cms->getResult()) {
    echo "Detected CMS: ".$cms->getResult();
} else {
    echo "CMS couldn't be detected";
}
```

gives me this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DetectCMS' not found in D:\Projects\Scraper\ccc.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in D:\Projects\Scraper\ccc.php on line 12
```

here is my file structure:

[image: File structure]

would anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong with this information? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you included the namespace?

Comment: to be completely honest, I'm not 100% sure what namespaces are yet, so I'm guessing no

Comment: use DetectCMS;

Add that line to your file after the <?php

Comment: still errors, unfortunately
`PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'DetectCMS' has no effect in D:\Projects\Scraper\ccc.php on line 2` as well as the other error

Comment: `$cms = new \DetectCMS\DetectCMS($domain);`

Comment: ^ that or use \DetectCMS\DetectCMS;

Comment: still errors :(

Comment: Did you execute `composer install` in your project directory? 'Cause I don't see this dependency in vendor/

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did (but I'm having second doubts). Doing the command again gives me an error `[InvalidArgumentException]
  A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator.` which I'm guessing has to do with the edits of the composer.json I made due to the comments below

Answer (score 1):

I think to include a class using the autoloader,in your class, you must do something about it:

in your composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4" :{"DetectCMS": "DetectCMS"}
}
```

after in your class DetectCMS.php:

```
<?php
   use DetectCMS\DetectCMS;
```

or

```
<?php

$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('DetectCMS', __DIR__.'DetectCMS');
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: in your composer.json

Comment: in your composer.json     "autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {"App\\" : "App"}
}

Comment: Why would you add .php to a use namespace?

Comment: it probably is somewhere in there - `"autoload":{
        "psr-4":{ "DetectCMS": "DetectCMS" }
    }`

Comment: in your class cms.php do it:                                                                          require "vendor/autoload.php";                                                                       use DetectCMS\DetectCMS;

Comment: both those statements are in there, but it still can't find the class - I must be doing something wrong